# convert partial to string from active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, facebook, facebooker

HI friends,

I have a situation where i have to convert a partial into string from Active-Record.

Here is the code:

```
Facebooker::Session.create(Facebooker.api_key, Facebooker.secret_key).send_email(
      facebook_user_id,
      "MAIL_SUBJECT",
      (:partial=>"some/partial")              
    )
```

This is being called from a model.

TO convert the partial into string, i resorted to render_to_string method and called it using:

```
ActionController::Base.new.send("render_to_string",{:partial=>"some/partial"})
```

But its throwing errors.

Any help please......

Comment: Knowing which errors will help

Comment: Because, i was using ActionController::Base, it is expecting a request object. But this call is made from a RAKE_TASK. The error says "request is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to call controller code from models, you are doing something wrong. It looks like you want to send an email, maybe look at ActionMailer? Or explain better *what* you are trying to do and *why* you're putting that in the model code and not controller code.